# debugging with gdb without sources

Tags: c++, gdb

I have to debug a program with gdb. This program is compiled with debug options with gcc.
My problem is that the sources are not in the same machine I use to debug and run this program. I can't use remote gdb debugging. Is there a way to now the line/file location when advancing in gdb? Is there some other solutions for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: @AStopher Well, when i try to do the research, this page comes up first in the search results. Never tell people to google the problem first on stackoverflow, you will get them stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @Youda008 That was 6 years ago... back then the top result was literally what the OP copied and pasted into their answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can debug it with the assembly code.

`objdump -d` shows all the contents. Then run `gdb` with break at`main` function, and `ni` to run the next instruction(assembly). Oh, don't forget to enable `display $pc` will help you.

The above advice is only for toy code.

If you have installed IDA(and the plugin), you can use its `restore to C code` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing a `segmentation fault`, you may use core dump on linux machine by enabling it

> ulimit -c unlimited

then transfer the core dump file to the other machine where you've got the source and run gdb with coredump file to identify where in the code you are getting the segmentation fault.

Answer (score -1):

I found the command `info line` in gdb which shows the location in source file, even if gdb did not find the source files. This workaround seems OK for me.